# How can I display alert only once in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

My case like this :

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/shop/payment/checkout' || window.location.pathname == '/shop/detail' || window.location.pathname == '/shop') {
    alert('Your data has been removed')
    localStorage.removeItem("cartCache")
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseUrl+'/shop/delete-cache',
        data: {_token: _token},
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success==1) 
                window.location = "/shop";
        }, 
        error: function(request, status, error) { 
            console.log('error')
        }
    });
}
```

If the url accessed meets the condition of `if` then it will delete session by ajax and redirect to the url `/shop`

My problem is if redirect to url `/shop`, it will check again and display alert message again. So on and on

I want if the alert message appears and reload to the url `/shop`, it does not check anymore and displays the alert message

How can I do it?

**EDIT**:

After the answer given, I wrapped my code like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("cartCache") !== null) {
    ...
}
else {
        alert('Your data has been removed')
        localStorage.removeItem("cartCache")
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl+'/shop/delete-cache',
            data: {_token: _token},
            success: function(response){
                if(response.success==1) 
                    window.location = "/shop";
            }, 
            error: function(request, status, error) { 
                console.log('error')
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It does not work as intended.

Comment: Use a variable that gets incremented when you alert. Check if it's still zero before you do. You could put the var in localStorage.

Comment: alert is a bad practice in this case. Use toastr  like library.

Comment: Check if the `cartCache` item exists in your `if` statement

Comment: You're telling the user that it's session has been removed before even sending the request to the server, which may fail and the session will not be destroyed properly O.o

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 2):

Before removing, you could first check if the local storage data is still there. Put this before the `alert`:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("cartCache") === null) return;
```

... assuming this code is within a function. But you get the idea. Or you can combine it with the `if` you already have (a bit improved):

```
if(['/shop/payment/checkout', '/shop/detail', '/shop'].includes(window.location.pathname) 
        && localStorage.getItem("cartCache") !== null) {
    // ...etc.
```

Comment: See my update question. I must delete session in server side and after that reload the page to update data

Comment: Yes, but if the local storage data is no longer there, it means you already did that. Actually, you added the code I suggested to your question, but inverted the condition... That is wrong.

Comment: Yes. But my case after remove cache in local storage, it also remove cache in session(by server side) and reload the page to `/shop` to update data

Comment: Indeed, I understand. That is what will happen on the first time this code is executed. NB: it is not nice to update your question with code provided in answers. Now my answer looks stupid.

Comment: There is nothing to update. Please apply the code as I suggested it.

Comment: It seems you still do not understand what I mean. My point is I want display alert message only once after delete session and reload to url `/ shop`

Comment: I understand exactly what you mean. With this code the `alert` will only be displayed if the `.removeItem()` method was not yet executed before.